# Looking for the Ubuntu wallpaper with the satellite and blue sky?

Tags: desktop-background

I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find it, anyone have a link to the wallpaper? Not even sure if it's an Ubuntu wallpaper, but I've seen it around on a couple screenshots in the past.

Specifically:

[image: Satellite wallpaper with car]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are many wallpaper packages in the repositories, have you tried to install them to see if it's in one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got it under `/usr/share/backgrounds/edubuntu-stargazer.png`, but I have all wallpapers packages from previous Ubuntu's installed. There you go:

[image]

Yup, it can be installed with `sudo apt install edubuntu-wallpapers`.

Comment: From Edubuntu's official website: https://www.edubuntu.org/sites/default/files/docimages/wallpapers-oneiric/edubuntu-stargazer-full.png.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a multiscreen version of the same wallpaper
https://www.reddit.com/r/multiwall/comments/9s6nn2/5760x1200_edubuntu_stargazer/